# List with unknown dimension

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a long list of lists, called Evlist in the following example, which I have to extract information from to be put into new lists Ev and w. I do this with the following code:

```
  i = 0;
    Do[
 If[  Evlist[[j, 3]] == 902, i = i + 1; k = 1, k = k + 1];
 w[[i]] = Evlist[[j, 5]];
 Ev[[i, k]] = Evlist[[j]],
 {j, 1, nf}
  ]
```

Here 'nf' is a large number (~ 10000) which is known. However, the maximum value of the index 'i' is not known beforehand, but will only emerge at the end of the loop.
My problem is that Mathematica requires a definition of the list Ev and w before it evaluates the loop. For example something like

```
w = Table[0, {i, Nevents}]
```

where, however, Nevents (= max(i)) is not known before the loop is executed.

How can I work with a list the dimension of which is not known beforehand?

Comment: Using a loop is not the Mathematica way for selecting items from a list. Look up "Select" or "Cases" from the help

Comment: Consider also that in Mathematica list indices start at 1, not 0. Please include in your question a small portion of your `Evlist`, and explain in words your selection criteria and desired output. I am sure that somebody will then show you a more idiomatic implementation using `Select` or `Cases`.

Comment: If you can give us more information, we can probably help. Keep in mind that if `Evlist[[1, 3]]` is not 902, your code will immediately fail. The 2nd and 3rd lines of the `Do` loop will run on every single loop. Is that ok? What "shape" should `Ev` be? It looks like you're trying to put the whole row of `Evlist` into the `k`th column of `Ev`. Is that correct? Should the other entries be padded with zeroes or would `{{0, 0, 0, 0,}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 0 ,0 ,0}}` be okay? For working with lists of unknown length, there are `AppendTo` and `Sow`/`Reap`, but there's almost certainly a better way.